# how to parse pdf document in iphone or ipad?

Tags: iphone

I am making one application in which i want to parse pdf document.I dont know how to implement.Please provide me some sample code and document.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the pdf documentation. http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=51502

Answer (score 0):

i hope my googling is useful for you find below link  https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit   ` documentManager=[MFDocumentManager documentManagerWithFilePath:@"give book path here"];

NSString *someText = [[documentManager wholeTextForPage:[self.currentPage intValue]+1 withProfile:NULL]copy];
`
the above two lines solve your problem.